# Converting string to DateTime failing

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string variable whose data will be the format below.

> 18-03-2015 16:39:15

i'm trying to convert it to a valid DateTime with hour/minute/second but so far the line below fails.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("18-03-2015 16:39:15", "dd-MM-yyyy h:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use uppercase `H` or `HH`, so `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:m:s"` with this time: 16:39:15.

See: [The "HH" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#HH_Specifier)

So lowercase is from  1 through 12 and uppercase for 24h format. If you use `H` or `HH` depends on if `4:39:15`  is possible or `04:39:15`. A single `H` supports both formats, so with or without a leading zero, whereas `HH` only allows `04:39:15`.

Comment: i have made the change but still with that sample string, dt returns as "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: It either throws an exption or returns a valid `DateTime` since you are not using `DateTime.TryParseExact`. So is it the real code that you've shown? If i test it it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `HH:mm:ss` in format

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("18-03-2015 16:39:15", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// So: dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") is 18-03-2015 16:39:15
```

[Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) are some examples of formatting the date with samples